# Pytorch runtime not included when project is built as a jar

Tags: kotlin, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, onnxruntime, djl

We have our ONNX model, and we're trying to use it in our app. Running the project from the IDE works just fine, but running the jar file produces this error. We debugged this issue and found that the supportedEngines in IDE runtime includes ONNXRuntime and PyTorch, but the JAR file includes ONNXRuntime only. The issue happens when we reach StackBatchifier.batchify(), on String inputName = ((NDArray)inputs[0].get(i)).getName();

We have the following dependencies in our gradle file:
api("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.18.0") api("ai.djl:model-zoo:0.21.0-SNAPSHOT") api("ai.djl.huggingface:tokenizers:0.21.0-SNAPSHOT") api("ai.djl.pytorch:pytorch-model-zoo:0.21.0-SNAPSHOT") api("ai.djl.onnxruntime:onnxruntime-engine:0.19.0") api("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.7.20")

Do we need to put any jar configurations for it to work?

Error Message
Exception in thread "main" ai.djl.translate.TranslateException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This NDArray implementation does not currently support this operation
at ai.djl.inference.Predictor.batchPredict(Predictor.java:189)
at ai.djl.inference.Predictor.predict(Predictor.java:126)
at ProfanityPredictionModel.predict(ProfanityPredictionModel.kt:30)
at TestModel.main(TestModel.kt:18)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This NDArray implementation does not currently support this operation
at ai.djl.ndarray.NDArrayAdapter.getAlternativeArray(NDArrayAdapter.java:1225)
at ai.djl.ndarray.NDArrayAdapter.getNDArrayInternal(NDArrayAdapter.java:1173)
at ai.djl.ndarray.NDArrays.stack(NDArrays.java:1825)
at ai.djl.ndarray.NDArrays.stack(NDArrays.java:1785)
at ai.djl.translate.StackBatchifier.batchify(StackBatchifier.java:52)
at ai.djl.inference.Predictor.processInputs(Predictor.java:217)
at ai.djl.inference.Predictor.batchPredict(Predictor.java:177)
... 3 more

Answer (score 0):

DJL uses ServiceLoader, when you creating your far jar, the service loader resource is not merged properly.

You can use [com.github.johnrengelman.shadow](https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl-demo/blob/master/development/fatjar/build.gradle#LL3C8-L3C39) gradle plugin or [maven-shade-pluging](https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl-demo/blob/master/development/fatjar/pom.xml#L106-L122) to build your fatjar.

You can find examples about [How to distribute DJL application](https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl-demo/tree/master/development/fatjar)